# Multi valued attributes in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

A database schema with a relation Employee whose attributes are as shown below, with types specified for multi-valued attributes.

```
Employee = (ename, ChildrenSet multiset(Children), SkillSet multiset(Skills))
Children = (name, birthday)
Skills = (type, ExmSet setoff(Exams))
Exams = (year, city)
```

1. Define the above schema, with appropriate types for each attribute.
2. Find the name of all employees who have a child born on or after January 1, 2000
3. Find those employees who took an examination for the skill type “typing” in the city 
       "Dayton"
4. List all skill types in the relation Employee.

please can u help me.

Comment: What does 'multiset' mean in this context?

Comment: @Daniel: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Answer (score 0):

**Define the above schema, with appropriate types for each attribute.**

```
Employees
{
    Employee_id, int, PK
    Name, nvarchar(50)        
}
Childs
{
    Child_id, int, PK
    Employee_id, int, FK
    Name, nvarchar(50)
    Birthday, date
}
Skills
{
    Skill_id, int, PK
    Employee_id, int, FK
    Type, nvarchar(50)
}
Exams
{
    Exam_id, int, PK
    Skill_id, int, FK
    Year, int
    City, nvarchar(50)
}
```

**Find the name of all employees who have a child born on or after January 1, 2000**

```
MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();

var result = from e in db.Employees
             join c in db.Childs
             on e.Employee_id equals c.Employee_id
             where e.Birthday >= new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
             select e;
```

**Find those employees who took an examination for the skill type “typing” in the city "Dayton"**

```
var result = from e in db.Employees
             join s in db.Skills
             on e.Employee_id equals s.Employee_id
             join x in db.Exams
             on s.Skill_id equals x.Skill_id
             where s.Type.Equals("typing") && x.City.Equals("Dayton")
             select e;
```

**List all skill types in the relation Employee**

```
var result = from e in db.Employees
             join s in db.Skills
             on e.Employee_id equals s.Employee_id
             select new EmployeeSkill() 
             {
                 EmployeeName = e.Name,
                 SkillType = s.Type
             };
```

bottom line... **Linq2Sql** rules :)

now... you just need to convert Linq to SQL and you have your homework done ;)

*(you didn't expected to get all done here, right?)*